# building a schema mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, schema

Whilst building the following schema

```
'use strict';
var User = mongoose.model('checkIn')

var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var checkIn = new Schema({
    email: {
        type: String
        // default:User.local.email
    },
    checkInDate: {
        type:Date,
        default:Date.now()
    }
})
module.exports = mongoose.model('User', checkIn);
```

I encountered the following error message

[image: Error message]

How do I fix this?

Comment: What happens if you remove that line `var User = mongoose.model('checkIn')`?

Comment: You should put "var mongoose = require('mongoose');" before "var User = mongoose.model('checkIn');".

Answer (score 0):

The error clearly says, "cannot read property of undefined". That means "mongoose" is undefined when it reaches `var User = mongoose.model('checkIn')`. Of course, because the require statement `var mongoose = require('mongoose');` comes afterwards. You should put the require statement first so that 'mongoose' is available when you call model property on it.